# Asset model missing required attr_accessor with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am trying to upload more than 1 file asset to a movie. I keep receiving an error `Asset model missing required attr_accessor for 'asset_file_name'` and I am not sure why, here is my code:

asset.rb model

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movie

  has_attached_file :asset
end
```

movie.rb model

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :assets
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets

  validates :title, presence: true

  default_scope order: 'movies.created_at DESC'
end
```

I have also ran `rails g paperclip movie asset` which generated the following migration file

```
class AddAttachmentAssetToMovie < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :movies, :asset_file_name, :string
    add_column :movies, :asset_content_type, :string
    add_column :movies, :asset_file_size, :integer
    add_column :movies, :asset_updated_at, :datetime
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :movies, :asset_file_name
    remove_column :movies, :asset_content_type
    remove_column :movies, :asset_file_size
    remove_column :movies, :asset_updated_at
  end
end
```

And here is my "create assets" migration that came from when I generated the asset model:

```
class CreateAssets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :assets do |t|
    t.string :asset_file_name
    t.integer :asset_file_size
    t.string :asset_content_type
    t.datetime :asset_updated_at
    t.text :asset_description
    t.integer :movie_id

    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

Can any suggest why i would be receiving the error `Asset model missing required attr_accessor for 'asset_file_name'`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Newer versions of Rails are (correctly) paranoid about mass assignment.  Add `attr_accessible :asset_file_name` in the Asset model to declare that it's OK for your database to accept external parameter input on a request.

To be even safer, uncomment `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true` in your `application.rb` (and then test everything) so that you are forced to think "yeah, that's fine and nothing bad will happen" for any attributes that you let users update.

Comment: Hi tharrison, i wish this were the case for this but I've already tried that and the same thing happens. I really don't understand where this is coming from.

Comment: Thanks harrison, you were right, I had a bad branch from a while ago that i was working on and had not realized it was old rails, this was all that was required, thanks!